# How to get row data onSelect event in ngx datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am new to angular and ngx datatable. how to get row data on mouse click event

```
onClick(event) {
// I need to get row data here 
}
```

Comment: You should really do more research or attempt to google your questions first. If your question requires something further then you need to add in depth explanation.

Answer (score 23):

Just use (activate)="onActivate($event)" property on ngx-datatable like this

```
<ngx-datatable #table
    ....
    (activate)="onActivate($event)"
    ....
>
```

Then in TS file, use this method

```
onActivate(event) {
    if(event.type == 'click') {
        console.log(event.row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### component.html file

```
(activate)="onActivate($event)"

OR

(select)="onSelect($event)"
```

#### component.ts file

```
onActivate(event) {
    if(event.type == 'click') {
        console.log(event.row);
    }
}

onSelect(event) {
    //event.type is undefined, use below:

    console.log(event.selected);
}
```

#### Note

- If you are using `(activate)` event, you will get `event`, `row`, `rowElement`, `type`
- If you are using `(select)` event, you will only get `selected`

Comment: (activate), not (activated)

Answer (score 1):

They have an example right here in the documentation

http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#single-selection

Source code:

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/selection/selection-single.component.ts